# Steps to setup mongo replica set

Tags: mongodb

I am having problems setting up a mongo replica set.  I have 2 servers and want one to be primary and one to be secondary.

On primary machine in mongod.conf:

```
replSet=rs1
```

Then in the console I type:

```
rs.initiate()
```

Which works great.  rs.config() shows:

```
{
  _id: "rs1",
  version: 1,
  members: [
    {
      _id: 0,
      host: "myhost1:27017"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is where things get messy.  What am I supposed to do on the second machine?  I have modified the mongod.conf to point to the same replica set name 'rs1'.  I start the sever and all is well.

Am I supposed to do an rs.initiate() on the second machine?  If so both instances now think that they are the 'PRIMARY'.

If I try to do an rs.add(...) on the first server to add the second server:

```
rs.add("myhost2:27017")
```

I get an error:

```
{
    "errmsg" : "need most members up to reconfigure, not ok : myhost2:27017",
    "code" : 13144,
    "ok" : 0
}
```

if I do an rs.initiate() on the second machine and then an rs.config() I get:

```
{
  _id: "rs1",
  version: 1,
  members: [
    {
      _id: 0,
      host: "myhost2:27017"
    }
  ]
}
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Here is my /etc/hosts file in case I messed something up there:

host1:

```
127.0.0.1   myhost1
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost4.localdomain6
```

host2:

```
127.0.0.1   myhost2
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost4.localdomain6
```

Comment: Can the 2 machines see each other over the network on the port stated?  check a telnet and ensure you get connectivity first and let us know.  Also, show us your /opt/config/mongodb file please.

Comment: They can see each other.  I have tried starting over a number of times with no luck.  added what is in my /etc/hosts file just in case that is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Your hosts were unable to resolve the hostnames you gave to actual IPs, since those were missing in the `/etc/hosts` file.

## How to solve

1. The hosts files on the all the machines must resolve the IPs of the respective machines to their respective hostnames.

   For example

   ```
   192.168.0.1 myhost1
   192.168.0.2 myhost2
   127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
   ::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
   ```

   Make sure all hostnames are resolved correctly by pinging each *other* host from each host, eg.

   ```
   myhost1 $ ping myhost2
   ```
2. Please [read the docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/replication/) thoroughly and make sure you understood them.
3. Proceed to step 2 until you really got it.
4. You only have to call `rs.initiate()` **once** and only on one machine, then use `rs.add()` on the same machine to add replica set members.

With your setup, you need an additional node or an [arbiter](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-arbiter/)

## Personal note

Please do not take this personal, but you lack basic system administration skills, and that's put politely.

**For your own sake: Do not run MongoDB for production until you acquired basic system and MongoDB administration skills!**

I'd look for [RHCSA](https://www.redhat.com/en/services/certification/rhcsa) **first** (works for CentOS as well) and  [M102, M202 and maybe even MongoDB DBA at MongoU](http://university.mongodb.com) later (without basic sysadmin skills, the latter won't help you much).

Comment: Hard not to take that personal :/  Non the less I do appreciate you taking time to answer my question.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @lostintranslation I was just trying to make my point clear ;) I am pretty sure you have skills in different areas. MongoU classes are free, only the DBA exam isn't free. All in all, getting basic skills takes a few weeks of focussed work and some $600 *including* certifications. Good for SLAs, I might add.

Comment: Sure and agreed.  However I think its wrong to assume anyones situation.  You can't leave a bold title 'Personal note', then say don't take it personal.

Comment: Well, it is personal *by me* ;) No harm done?

Comment: Correct, no harm done.  The fact that you took time to help is awesome.

Comment: Just some feedback of my own, It's really great and helpful that the links to training were included, that's often overlooked.  Putting it politely to me though would be "It's great to reach out here for help, if you're running this in production though be careful as there are a lot of other issues that come up which are much more complex.  Having this in prod like this could lead to major issues.  Consider training before moving too fast.
I only state this because in StackExchange we try to keep things really upbeat.  Anyways, glad you guys got it resolved!

Comment: @AliRazeghi Sorry, I tend to be a bit rough, but not with malvolent intent, quite the contrary. Will keep that in mind, however.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I have the same thing happen to me sometimes.  Just recently I've been learning how important it is in my career to give people the 'warm and fuzzy' feeling every time I talk to them.  It's pretty alien to me as well, but personally I've found it really useful for career related movement.  Thanks!

Comment: IMHO, the "Personal note" section has no place in SO. It's hostile, elitist and, worst of all, unfriendly.

Comment: @ank It may be "sound" unfriendly, I admitted that. But I repudiate the accusation of hostility and elitism to the utmost degree possible. If it was hostile, is wouldn't have taken the time to answer the question in the first place. I chose the hard words for a single reason: to make it unambiguously clear to OP that he or she is lacking the skill set to run  MongoDB in a production environment. And if the statement were elitist, I surely wouldn't have pointed the OP to MongoU and RHCSA. OP got that. Putting the boot in self-righteously isn't but a single bit better.

Comment: Pointing out an aggressive statement is in no way on par with making the aggressive statement in the first place... "and that's putting it mildly"

Comment: @ank So, and in what way did your comment further anyone's knowledge, be it self- or expert knowledge? OP's comment was informative. Ali's was pointing out a better way. Yours is trying to make a point just because.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I'm helping build a better community. Peace, mate, and good luck - let's hope no potential employer finds your comments here tied to your name.

Comment: @ank that's the difference: I hope they do. ;) and while we are at teaching lessons: in which way did your comment make the community better? Compared to Ali's for example?